# request.Session() headers and get/post headers

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm confused about request.Session headers and the headers parameter under get/post/etc.  I'm using python 3.9.2 with requests 2.25.1.  lets say:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.header = header
etc.. .
```

and then under get, post, etc. you can pass a dict of headers with the headers parameter.

so here are my questions.

1st, are headers supposed to be of type dict with key/value pairs OR list of paired tuples?
2nd, if you set the session headers, do they get replaced, merged, or mixed somehow when you also apply a get/post parameters headers?
3nd, what is the proper way to handle headers when you have session headers and parameter headers working at the same time?

thank you in advance, Lucas

Answer (score 3):

1.headers supposed to be of type dict with key/value pairs OR list of paired tuples?

> #: A case-insensitive dictionary of headers to be sent on each

2.do they get replaced, merged, or mixed somehow when you also apply a get/post parameters headers?

> Any dictionaries that you pass to a request method will be merged with
> the session-level values that are set. The method-level parameters
> override session parameters.

```
headers=merge_setting(request.headers, self.headers, dict_class=CaseInsensitiveDict),
```